# MYSQL - get data from table that are not paired with another table

Tags: mysql

I cant figure out one sql query. I need to get data from table, that are not paired in another table. So my limited knowlage is not enought here.

Lets say we have 3 tables **client** - **category** - **client_category**

**TABLE CLIENT**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | client 1 |
| 2 | client 2 |

**TABLE category**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | category 1 |
| 2 | category 2 |
| 3 | category 3 |

**TABLE client_category**

| id | id_client | id_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

| client | category |
| --- | --- |
| client 1 | category 2 |
| client 1 | category 3 |

This also need to work with more clients and categories.

Comment: it doesn't make much sense, if we can't put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT client.name, category.name
FROM client
CROSS JOIN category
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM client_category
                   WHERE client.id = client_category.id_client
                     AND category.id = client_category.id_category )
```

or

```sql
SELECT client.name, category.name
FROM client
CROSS JOIN category
LEFT JOIN client_category ON client.id = client_category.id_client
                         AND category.id = client_category.id_category
WHERE client_category.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in all *possible* links between **client** and **category**, that do not exist in **client_category**

```
SELECT
   c.name, y.name
FROM client c
CROSS JOIN category y
LEFT JOIN client_category cc ON cc.id_client = c.id AND cc.id_category = y.id
WHERE cc.id IS NULL
ORDER BY c.id, y.id
```

output:

| name | name |
| --- | --- |
| client 1 | catgory 2 |
| client 1 | category 3 |

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86581831ce37e828a931e8baf25cbdc8)